# Extracting amount using regular expression from text

Tags: python, regex

I am newbie in Regular expressions,I want to extract amount from a given text,Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
msg='He was paid USD 2,000.00 & USD 500 on 19-02-2018 at 08:15:24.'

pattern = re.compile(r'USD\s+(\d+)')

matches = pattern.finditer(msg)


for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

I want output as 2000 and 500,But currently I am getting USD 2 as output.Please help.
Note:The original message is very long but all the amounts have USD preceding them.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/L0sKWR

Comment: If you are waiting for a solution with a single line of code to extract `2000` from `2,000.00`, bear in mind you cannot match discontinuous texts within one match operation.

Comment: `(?<= )(?:\d+[.,]?)+(?= )`?? ie `re.findall(r'(?<= )(?:\d+[.,]?)+(?= )',msg)`  but this will capture other numbers like 02, 17,87.87,87 etc.. just to anchor it to the values, if at all we have a specified currency, then it will be necessary to do `re.findall(r'(?<=USD )(?:\d+[.,]?)+(?= )',msg)`

Answer (score 1):

This will be the correct pattern: `r'USD\s+([\d,\.]+)'`

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'USD\s+([\d,\.]+)')
>>> matches = pattern.finditer(msg)
>>> for match in matches:
...     print(match)
...
<re.Match object; span=(12, 24), match='USD 2,000.00'>
<re.Match object; span=(27, 34), match='USD 500'>
```

You need to include the commas (`,`) and dots (`.`) in your regex. `\d` will match only the numbers.

Once you remove them from the final matches, your job is done.

Comment: What if I only want to display the first amount in a line i.e only USD 2,000.00.I will be reading a file line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It will work.

```
USD\s+(\d+)(,*)(\d+)
```